# Vue 3 composition API: can not access reactive array value programmatically, only in template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In a component, i defined a reactive constant (isn't that paradox?) like this:

```
const form = reactive({
    name: null,
    fruits: new Array(),
})
```

The value for **name** is set via a text input field.
The value for **fruits** is set via a group of checkboxes.

when i want to get the values of each programmatically using this function:

```
const makeObj = () => {
    console.log("form.name", form.name)
    console.log("form.fruits", form.fruits)
}
```

... i can only access `form.name`, but `form.fruits`returns some Proxy object:

[image: console.log]

**BUT:** I can access the elements of the array directly with `form.fruits[0]`returning the first item, e.g. `Banana`.

**Question:**
How can i access the array value of form.fruits? Do i have to convert the reactive array `form.fruits` to a "normal" array somehow?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. If you don't get a decent answer soon, please consider creating and posting a valid [mre] code post in your question. The link should explain this.

Comment: No, there is no need to convert anything

Comment: How does the answer solve your issue -- again, what exactly is your issue??

Comment: Thank you! For anybody who is also confused by the string representation of the reactive array: check `JSON.stringify(form.fruits)`

Comment: So, in other words, other than confusion over String representation, your code was in fact working, and you had no issue accessing the array within the reactive variable...

Comment: exactly! I hope this dialog helps somebody having the same confusion over the string representation of reactive arrays in Vue 3 .

Comment: Sigh, please see [my wasted efforts](http://shorturl.at/cFJ45) on this issue, time that can no longer be retrieved. In the future, please show more and explain more, including a [mre].

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort! Next time i will provide an MRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy is Vue’s reactivity system that allows to track dependencies and changes to the array. Pretend it isn't there :) You can do with it everything you can with plain array.

```js
const { reactive, onMounted } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const form = reactive({
      name: null,
      fruits: new Array()
    })
    const makeObj = () => {
      form.name = 'aa'
      form.fruits = [1,2,3]
      console.log("form.name", form.name)
      console.log("form.fruits", form.fruits)
    }
    onMounted(() => {
      makeObj()
    })
    return { form }
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  {{ form }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. your example gives me exactly the same result on the console as i get, with this Proxy object as a return value instead of the values of the array. I am not working with JS on a regular basis, pardon my question. I was confused with the string representation of the console.log output. So i ran `JSON.stringify(form.fruits)`seeing that it gives exactly the expected result.